What are the alternatives to using a MemoryStream twice here?
I'm trying to write code that stamps a passport with the system users name, date and an image of their signature (which I store as a varbinary in the sql database and byte in the model).
Here is my code:
private async void button_ApprovePassport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ProcessPassportPdfAsync();
}

private async Task ProcessPassportPdfAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Check if a document is selected
        if (gridView_PortalDocs.IsSelected())
        {
            var PortalDoc = gridView_PortalDocs.GetSelectedDataRow<PortalDocumentInfoModel>();
            if (PortalDoc != null)
            {
                EmployeePortalService EPS = new EmployeePortalService();
                if (PortalDoc.PortalFileID == null)
                {
                    cGlobal.ShowErrorMessage("PortalFileID is null. Cannot retrieve document.");
                    return;
                }

                var Data = await EPS.GetDocument(PortalDoc.PortalFileID);
                if (Data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data.FileData))
                {
                    // Convert base64 string to byte array
                    byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Data.FileData);

                    // Create a memory stream from the byte array
                    using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                    {
                        // Process the PDF (stamp it)
                        using (MemoryStream processedStream = StampPdf(inputStream))
                        {
                            // Save the processed PDF to a temporary file
                            string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"StampedPassport_{Guid.NewGuid()}.pdf");
                            File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, processedStream.ToArray());

                            // Open the PDF with the default viewer
                            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(tempFilePath) { UseShellExecute = true });

                            // Convert the processed stream back to a base64 string
                            string processedBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(processedStream.ToArray());

                            // Using the API for the document reupload here

                            // Update the PortalFiles table here

                            MessageBox.Show("Passport PDF processed and approved successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cGlobal.ShowErrorMessage("The document data could not be retrieved from the server or is empty.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cGlobal.ShowErrorMessage("The selected document information is invalid.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cGlobal.ShowInfoMessage("Please select a document to process.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cGlobal.ShowErrorMessage($"An error occurred while processing the passport PDF: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

private MemoryStream StampPdf(MemoryStream inputStream)
{
    // Get the user's signature and first name from the controller
    // Use Stefi's for testing then switch to cGlobal.SystemUserID
    var SystemUserSignature = Controller.GetSystemUserSignature(345);

    // Check if the signature was retrieved successfully
    if (SystemUserSignature == null || SystemUserSignature.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("User signature not found. Please add one in Access Control.");
    }

    // Retrieve the first user's details (assuming there's at least one entry)
    var user = SystemUserSignature[0];

    // Ensure we're using UTF-8 encoding (important for PdfSharp)
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    // Load the existing document
    PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(inputStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

    // Get the first page (you might want to stamp all pages)
    PdfPage page = document.Pages[0];

    // Create graphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    // Create fonts using system fonts
    XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 12);
    XFont largeFont = new XFont("Arial", 24);

    // Create a semi-transparent brush for the background of the stamp
    XColor stampColor = XColor.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0);  // Semi-transparent red
    XBrush stampBrush = new XSolidBrush(stampColor);

    // Draw a rectangle for the stamp background
    gfx.DrawRectangle(stampBrush, 50, 50, 250, 100);

    // Add text for the stamp
    gfx.DrawString("APPROVED", largeFont, XBrushes.White, new XRect(50, 50, 250, 50), XStringFormats.Center);

    // Add approval details
    gfx.DrawString($"By: {user.Forename}", font, XBrushes.White, new XRect(60, 100, 230, 25), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
    gfx.DrawString($"Date: {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}", font, XBrushes.White, new XRect(60, 125, 230, 25), XStringFormats.TopLeft);

    // If the signature is available, draw it on the PDF
    if (user.Signature != null && user.Signature.Length > 0)
    {
        // Load the signature image from the byte array
        using (var signatureImage = new MemoryStream(user.Signature))
        {
            XImage image = XImage.FromStream(signatureImage);
            gfx.DrawImage(image, 50, 150, 150, 50); // Position and size of the signature
        }
    }

    // Save the document to a new MemoryStream
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Save(outputStream, false);

    outputStream.Position = 0; // Reset stream position to the beginning
    return outputStream;
}

The error I'm getting is "An error occurred while processing the passport PDF: MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed". So I don't think you can use two MemoryStream's at once. What are my alternatives for achieving this?
All I've tried is doing it via MemorySteam really.
Edit: Following some of the comments I've tried something. The error is coming here:
                    XImage image = XImage.FromStream(signatureImage);

So I tried not disposing the memory stream explicitly
if (user.Signature != null && user.Signature.Length > 0)
{
    var signatureImage = new MemoryStream(user.Signature);
    XImage image = XImage.FromStream(signatureImage);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, 50, 150, 150, 50); // Position and size of the signature
}

I still seem to get the same error though.

Instead of modifying the inputStream directly, you can use a separate MemoryStream for writing the output PDF file.

What line give you the error? There is no issue using multiple memory streams at once. The error might be due to using a memory stream after it has been disposed. Possibly by XImage.FromStream(signatureImage), some classes require the stream to be open for the lifetime of the object, and DrawImage might keep a reference to the object, keeping it alive longer than the stream. I would consider just not disposing the memory streams, the memory will be collected regardless.

That error happens when someone calls GetBuffer on a MemoryStream and the internal buffer isn't marked as exposable. I don't see you creating MemoryStreams in such a way or calling GetBuffer yourself. So to understand this it may help when you tell us in what line you get this and maybe show the Stacktrace. We might guess something from it when it shows internal PdfSharp behavior.

Thank you for your suggestions. I'm getting the error here:
// If the signature is available, draw it on the PDF
if (user.Signature != null && user.Signature.Length > 0)
{
    // Load the signature image from the byte array
    using (var signatureImage = new MemoryStream(user.Signature))
    {
        XImage image = XImage.FromStream(signatureImage);
        gfx.DrawImage(image, 50, 150, 150, 50); // Position and size of the signature
    }
}

Specifically:
XImage image = XImage.FromStream(signatureImage);

You're right @JonasH

It might be a bug in the library. XImage.FromStream might try to be clever and check the type on the stream, and if a MemoryStream, use .GetBuffer. But that is not always allowed. You could try using this constructor with publiclyVisible set to true.

Okay thank you for all your comments I have the fix.
The error System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed.' occurs because XImage.FromStream() in PdfSharp tries to access the internal buffer of the MemoryStream, which is not public by default.
To fix this, I created a new MemoryStream with a writable buffer and copied the byte array into it. This allows XImage.FromStream() to access the stream without issues. Here's the solution:
if (user.Signature != null && user.Signature.Length > 0)
{
    // Create a writable MemoryStream with a public buffer
    MemoryStream signatureImage = new MemoryStream(user.Signature.Length);
    signatureImage.Write(user.Signature, 0, user.Signature.Length);
    signatureImage.Position = 0;  // Reset position to the beginning

    // Load the signature image from the writable MemoryStream
    XImage image = XImage.FromStream(signatureImage);
    gfx.DrawImage(image, 50, 150, 150, 50); // Position and size of the signature
}

This ensures PdfSharp can access the internal buffer of the memory stream.
Many thanks all who contributed!

This approach allocates new memory and creates a copy of the image data. It works, but is not efficient.

To create the MemoryStream, you can use code like this:
using Stream stream = new MemoryStream(user.Signature, 0, user.Signature.Length, true, true);

This creates a MemoryStream for the existing byte array that supports GetBuffer, thus avoiding the duplication of the bytes in memory.
With .NET Framework, GetBuffer worked for all MemoryStreams. With newer .NET versions you have to use a different constructor to allow GetBuffer.
